# Closing a Bootstrap Alert Automically after n seconds

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a new site using the Bootstrap Framework and have issues trying to automatically close a boot strap alert after n seconds.

The main page contains a modal login form.  Once a user attempts to login, providing the entered details are incorrect, i display a alert on the main page containing an error (wrong password, Unknown username etc).

So the alert appears fine, but i cant automatically close it, code below if anyone is able to help, thanks.

PHP (returns error and displays alert)

```
<?php

// show potential errors / feedback (from login object)
if (isset($login)) {
    if ($login->errors) {
        foreach ($login->errors as $error) {
            $AlertError = $error;

            echo '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert" id="loginerror">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
               <strong>' . $AlertError . '</strong>
               </div>';
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried calling a java script functions from the above PHP code to then close the alert with no luck

```
$("#loginerror").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
$("#loginerror").alert('close');
```

Comment: Why don't you start over and use this: http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html
because you need to learn first that you can't call javascript from PHP (or at least understand how javascript and PHP should communicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have a delay like `setTimeout()` and just fire the `.click()` on the close button:

```
if($('#loginerror').length){ // <-----checks if loginerror div is available
   setTimeout(function(){
      $('#loginerror').find('.close')[0].click();
   },1*1000);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a go